# Do YouTube uploads include metadata?

Tags: youtube, privacy

When uploading videos to YouTube do the video files include metadata that a viewer might be able to see like location and other personal details? Like the EXIF info from a photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add a video location and recording date in the advanced settings:

[image: Video location and recording date can be made public]

YouTube also takes [Spatial Media Metadata](https://github.com/google/spatial-media) that tell YouTube whether your video is 3D, spherical video, VR180, and so on.

Other than those, no metadata seem to get preserved when uploading.